# linq many to many query inside select

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, many-to-many

[image]

Here is my attempt to make a many to many linq request, but it doesn't work as expected. CVVM class has a property `ICollection<FormationVM> Formations`

```
var cv = (
    from c in context.CVs
    where c.Id == id
    select new CVVM
    {

        Id = id,    
        Formations = 
           from f in context.Formations
           from c2 in context.CVs
           where c2.Id == id 
           select new FormationVM
           {
               Id = form.Id,
               DateDebut = form.DateDebut,
               DateFin = form.DateFin,
               Ecole = form.Ecole,
               Description = form.Description,
               Diplome = form.Diplome
           }
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Why does `Model.Formations.Count()` return 3 instead of 2 in my View please ?

Comment: 1. [edit] 2. select code 3. ctrl-k. Now you're better off than you were.

Comment: Don't you need a join ?

Comment: "It doesn't work as expected" Alas you forgot to write your expectations. Please edit the question and write something like "I have a dbContext with a table of CVs and a table of Formations. Every CV has zero or more Formations, every Formation belongs to exactly one CV, using a foreign key: a simple one-to-many relation. Now given this DbContext, I want a query that returns ..."

Comment: Hi Harald, I didn't mention that because i thought it would be obvious enough showing the sql tables

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution. This code works :

```
using (Context context = new Context())
                {

                    var cv =
                                    (
                                        from c in context.CVs
                                        where c.Id == id && c.PersonneId == userId
                                        select new CVVM
                                        {
                                            Titre = c.Titre,
                                            MontrerPhoto = c.MontrerPhoto,
                                            Layout = c.Layout,
                                            Id = id,
                                            FormAction = "EditionTraitement",
                                            FormTitre = "Edition de ce CV",

                                             Formations = from form in c.Formations
                                                          where c.Id == id && c.PersonneId == userId
                                                          select new FormationVM
                                                         {
                                                             Id = form.Id,
                                                             DateDebut = form.DateDebut,
                                                             DateFin = form.DateFin,
                                                             Ecole = form.Ecole,
                                                             Description = form.Description,
                                                             Diplome = form.Diplome
                                                         }

                                        }).FirstOrDefault();

}
```